How to support a keyboard tray for holding a full size piano
I am building a desk and am installing a keyboard tray. The tray is as you would think, it sits under the desk and will be about 1400mm long made from basic 18mm ply. Not hardwood ply stuff.
The tray will have sliding bracket on either side connected to some wide ply at the sides underneath the desktop. The keyboard is around 14kg weight. So the ply will probably sag.
How do I avoid the sagging? I was going to double up the plywood as I have enough to do so. Will that be enough to stop it sagging overtime?
Is there anything else I can do to help it? Thank you.

Welcome to WSE. I'm not sure how you can fit a full-size piano under a desk.  This inquiry could use a dimensioned sketch of what you are planning including the weight.  Are you referring to a keyboard or a piano?

Sorry it's a keyboard around about 1400mm, on a sliding tray made of 18mm ply. Ply sides will like screwed onto a sliding rail like a drawer rail, and that rail will be screwed into a horizontal piece of wood which in turn is screwed into the desk frame. Frame for the desk is roughly sketched here. I'll update the post

OK well 14kg is actually a trivial weight for a drawer, even one of this width. Certainly the weakest runners I'm aware of will take this kind of weight no problem, but you might want to go up the food chain to ensure long-term service without the slides wearing too much leading to sticking points. Also, despite this being cheap ply, sagging might not be an issue, because the weight isn't at all in the centre. Presumably the keyboard has feet, and they're located in the typical location, the corners? This distributes the weight nearly at the ends, which is absolutely perfect for minimal sag.

However, reinforcing would not be a bad ideal if you feel you should/need to. Doubling up the thickness of ply would do that, but I'm sure is overkill (however, that's no reason not to if you want to). Lippings or one or more battens underneath will also provide significant stiffening.

That has a lot of similarities with a bookshelf. I'd put a lip on the front edge of the 18mm wood and maybe the back edge as well.    My dimensions are in inches.  The front lip also provides cover for the plywood edge grain.

Maybe a lip on the back edge sticking up to prevent things falling out the back?

I too wondered if a back lip could keep the keyboard from falling off the back however to assist with sagging, the lip needs to be below the shelf.  To perform as support and, to provide a backing so that things don't fall off, the back board would be both above and below thus, a dado comes to mind.

"however to assist with sagging, the lip needs to be below the shelf" Not so. The standard lipping used to be a simple strip attached front-only (in various ways) and they did fine.... still do, this style is still v. common. Obviously a lipping with a rebate as pictured IS better, but that's partly due to the greater amount of wood as much as the 'shelf' for the front of the panel to rest upon. A lipping at the back attached on top does work as a stiffener if it's attached firmly, preventing any possibility of it separating as the panel sags and the stiffer strip stays behind so to speak.

The edge treatment could be profiled to provide a slight "lip" for the moving drawer without sacrificing rigidity. For example, in reference to the image above, cutting the rebate/dado at 3/4" or 7/8 for the 5/8" shelf would give reasonable stability to the shelf, but also for the things on the shelf.

The front piece does several things.  Since it extends below the shelf, it is a lip that can be pulled out.  It's 1-1/4 inches top to bottom so the front of the shelf unit can handle a lot more weight than 5/8 inch plywood.  It's birch so, it's fairly strong and finishes nicely.  The quarter round routed in the bottom is decoration.  Finally, in addition to being glued to the plywood shelf, it has several #10 biscuits in it holding it to the plywood shelf.

Personally I'd round it over, rather than routing that decorative quarter round, because I have a habit of catching my rather long legs on things like this and a smooth curve with the largest radius I could get is less uncomfortable at that point


I was going to double up the plywood as I have enough to do so. Will that be enough to stop it sagging overtime?

I'm sure it would as noted in the Comments, but I believe it would be overkill (plus don't discount the extra weight for a panel of this size). This isn't a reason not to do it, but it needs to be factored in.
For me, a key issue here is that while this is similar to a floating shelf, the loading is quite light and it's not weighted towards the centre which is a significant contributor to a tendency to sag — shelves heavily weighted only at the edges tend to sag little, if at all. And presumably the keyboard has feet which will distribute the weight quite uniformly or exclusively towards each end.
One of the standard ways to stiffen a shelf (particularly if a manmade board material is used) is with a front 'nosing' or edging. There are multiple forms such a nosing can take and while the following image by no means shows all of them it gives you a range of options.

In general hardwood is used for these, however softwood is not completely ruled out, just make it beefier to compensate for the less-stiff material.
